# Python27: How can I loop this script with a CSV file of URLS?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use the following script, but instead of typing in the URL, I want it to loop and pull the URLs from Links.csv file. Eventually I want to export all the results into a new CSV file.

```
import csv
import urllib2
import re
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = open('Links.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

Links =[]

for row in csv_f:
    Links.append(row[0])

url = (Links)
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
Title = soup.find(id="Title")
Price = soup.find(id="price")

print Title.text, Price.text
f.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: loop over the list of urls?

Answer (score 0):

use functions

```
def get_title_and_price(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return soup.find(id="Title"),soup.find(id="price")

data = [(row[0],get_title_and_price(row[0]))for row in csv_f]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to work:  
`import csv 
import urllib2
import re
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = open('Links.csv', "r")

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

Links =[]

for row in csv_f:
    Links.append(row[0])

url = [Links]
 
def get_title_and_price(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return soup.find(id="Title"),soup.find(id="price")

data = [(row[0],get_title_and_price(row[0]))for row in csv_f]

print data
 
f.close()`

Comment: The response I get back is "[ ]" without any errors. Not sure if it has to do with the actual file itself, which is simple a list of urls.